# My OS won't starting

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu alongside my Windows 7 OS. But after the installation whenever I select Windows 7 from selection menu all it showing me is a blank purple screen. So I choosed "recommended repairs" from boot repair tool but it was still the same so I also tried update-grub but still it didn't worked. And now when I try to start Ubuntu its also showing a purple screen with some white dots along with the window to enter password and after I enter the password it just showing me a black screen with a cursor. It also saying that ASCI Video bus not found .

Edit: I just fixed Ubuntu by changing "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" in OS selection menu. But my windows is still showing that Purple screen.

Comment: Was Windows 7 working before?

Comment: It was working until I set up the duel boot with Ubuntu . Also I just fixed Ubuntu's purple screen problem by changing "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" in OS selection menu. But my windows7 is still showing that Purple screen

Comment: 1. `nomodeset` isn't a fix, it's a workaround. You probably need to install graphics drivers. 2. If Windows was working before and not now it probably has to do with how you resized its partition.

Comment: The purple login screen is normal. You can change it with your favorite wallpaper.